# How to heal crippled limbs in fallout 2 without high medic skill?

Tags: fallout-2

I got my arm crippled and didn't notice it for a while, to load the game would mean to loose like an hour of play (I know, I know)...

[image]

I have visited quite a few doctors, but no one seems to heal my crippled arm

**How to heal crippled limbs without high medic skill?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to go to Vault City Courtyard (not Vault 8) there's a doctor there, you can fix his auto-dock... (Vic can do it for you)

[image]

Then you need to inflict to yourself some damage as he will not heal your limbs at full health (you can use Super Stimpack and wait for it to come off to loose some health) he will then heal you for 300 caps...

Hope this saves you some time...